# Rails 4 - Acronym Controller Within a Namespace Giving 'Uninitialized Constant' Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create this controller in Rails 4:

```
Admin::EDMsController
```

In my initializers/inflections.rb file, I've defined the acronym:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
   inflect.acronym 'EDMs'
   inflect.acronym 'EDM'
end
```

My routes.rb file has:

```
namespace :admin do
  # ... some other resources ...
  resources :edms
end
```

And my controller is defined as follows in app/controllers/admin/edms_controller.rb:

```
class Admin::EDMsController < Admin::AdminController
end
```

When I try to access /admin/edms, I get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant Admin::EDMsController
```

What I've found so far:

- If I rename it to Admin::EdmsController and remove the inflection definitions (i.e. everything the same except not an acronym), it works
- If I move the whole thing out of the admin namespace into the root of my app (i.e. EDMsController, accessed via /edms), it works

It's also worth noting that I have other controllers and resources in the admin namespace which work correctly.

So it seems I can have an acronym controller, or a controller within a namespace, but not both.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think it´s because the acronym thingy, I looked for that in the api docs for rails 4 and I didn´t finnd it. Maybe it was removed.

Comment: @emerak Do you mean ActiveSupport::Inflector::Inflections.acronym? If so, it's still there http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html#method-i-acronym

Comment: mmm check the note about acronym pluralization, think that's the answer

Comment: @emerak Yeah, I did pass both the pluralized and non-pluralized version (see the second code block in my question above). I also tried swapping their order and disabling either the singular or plural versions, but no luck I'm afraid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug that was fixed in 4.2: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/14146

If you can't upgrade, this should work:

```
irb(main):001:0> ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) { |inflect| inflect.acronym 'Admin/EDMs' }
=> /Admin\/EDMs/
irb(main):002:0> 'Admin::EDMsController'.underscore
=> "admin/edms_controller"
```

Comment: I'm using Rails 6.0.2.2, and still, it's an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that using `irregular` works well because it forces certain starting word to translate directly to the result.

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'delta', 'deltas'
end
```

Comment: That didn't work. Tried inflect.irregular 'edm', 'EDMs' but no luck.